# Can not take more than one picture in Android

Tags: android

I can't take a picture for the second time. I try to take more pictures but I can't.
Can you help me find error and fix this?

Thanks

```
public class TakePicture extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    TextView testView;

    Button takePicture;
    ImageView view;
    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    PictureCallback rawCallback;
    ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
    PictureCallback jpegCallback;
    private final String tag = "VideoServer";
    boolean inPreview = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        takePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                captureImage();

            }
        });

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - raw");
            }
        };

        shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
            public void onShutter() {
                Log.i("Log", "onShutter'd");
            }
        };

        jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                // Set the Image to ImageView
                Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                        data.length);
                view.setImageBitmap(bitmapPicture);
                Random an = new Random();

                // Save the Image to SD Card
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                            "/sdcard/pictures/screenshots/" + an.nextInt()
                                    + ".jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");

                /**
                 * The two lines below are used to refresh the Surface View It
                 * works quickly then the general refresh by Default
                 **/
                stop_camera();
                start_camera();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

    }
    @Override public void onBackPressed()
    {    
      // Restart camera
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (camera != null) {
            Log.e(tag, "Camera was not null on back pressed!");
            try {
                camera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            // camera.release();
            // camera = null;
        }
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

    }

    private void captureImage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);

    }

    private void start_camera() {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
            return;
        }
        Camera.Parameters param;
        param = camera.getParameters();
        // modify parameter
        param.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
        param.setPreviewSize(176, 144);
        camera.setParameters(param);
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
            // camera.takePicture(shutter, raw, jpeg)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
            return;
        }
        inPreview = true;
    }

    private void stop_camera() {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        inPreview = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        start_camera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        stop_camera();

    }

}
```

below is layout file and androidmennifest file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Take Picture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mzubair.takepicture"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="view.TakePicture"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_take_picture" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please show your logcat

Answer (score 0):

try to add camera.startPreview(); before camera.takePicture();